# How does billing.save(); work?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart

I have made a checkout button in magento 1.7:

```
onclick="billing.save(); shipping.save(); checkout.save(); return false;"
```

This passes all the billing information except for Telephone.

I presume Telephone is part of billing, and does not have to be passed separately to billing.save();    Where can I find what billing.save(); should be passing?  How do I add components, specifically telephone, to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange. billing.save should pull the phone number in too as the standard function is along the lines of:

$billingAddress = $this->getRequest()->getParam(‘billing’);

Which includes the phone number into sales order etc.

All of the variables you want should be listed on this page:

/app/design/frontend/default//template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

Comment: but what part of the billing.phtml page makes it part of billing.save();?  If the id begins "billing:"?   How do I print the phone var to see if it is populated?  echo $billingAddress = $this->getRequest()->getParam(‘billing’);?

Comment: have you tried billingaddress.save();?

Comment: The checkout.xml page should shed light on what variables or blocks are taken into the "billing" parameter.

Comment: checkout.xml just gives phtml files called.  not sure  billing.save(); is defined in there...

Comment: If you look inside Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing located in /Checkout/Block/Onepage/Billing.php you will what happens inside of billing.phtml.

Look specifically for the method getAddress() as it will show you what and how the class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address is returned. Have you read and worked through this page - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/12052/

Comment: thanks for the link.  Thats basically what I did, turn off telephone, and put the telephone variable through the company variable.  More of a hack than a fix though.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Sweet. Glad you got there in the end :)